# Mysql Insert data from one table to another table

Tags: php, mysql

```
INSERT INTO table2 (firstname, lastname, middlename) SELECT firstname, lastname FROM table1 WHERE id = 1
```

How can I insert data for table2 'middlename' column? In my table1 there is only two column 'firstname' and 'lastname'

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `middlename` column from the list:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (firstname,lastname) 
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM table1 WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
INSERT INTO table2 (firstname, lastname, middlename) SELECT firstname, lastname, "NA" FROM table1 WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (firstname,lastname) SELECT firstname, lastname FROM table1
```

Leave middle name in table2 blank as you dont have record for that

Answer (score 0):

If it's a mandatory column (i.e. NOT NULL and no default defined), you'll have to select a constant.
Something like

```
insert into table2 (firstname, lastname, middlename)
select firstname, lastname, 'N/A' from table1 where id = 1;
```

If the column is optional, omit the column from the column list. Like

```
insert into table2 (firstname, lastname)
select firstname, lastname from table1 where id = 1;
```